# Multiple asp.net development server ports

Tags: asp.net, web, project, cassini, webdev.webserver

I've got a few projects and websites in my solution. When I debug a website, ports are opened for all the websites. I'm thinking this slows down my debugging. How do I switch off these extra ports rather than excluding the websites from the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this:

Set the "`Always Start When Debugging`" property to "`false`" for each of your website projects. Just click the Project in the Solution Explorer, hit F4. It's the first property in the list.

I had the same problem and this solved my problem!